# 5 Lined Rules of Inference Question

Tags: propositional-calculus

Use the rules of inference together with basic
logical equivalences to show that the following argument is valid. Name the
rule you use at each step.

w ∨ ¬z → r

s ∨ ¬w

¬t

z → t

¬z ∧ r → ¬s

—————–

∴ ¬w

I'm really not sure how to work through this problem, I've never worked on a 5 line inference question so I'm not sure how to grasp this.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

With $\lnot t$ and $z \to t$ derive $\lnot z$ [with [Modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens)].

With $\lnot z$ and $w ∨ ¬z → r$ derive $r$ [with [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) and [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)].

With $r$ and $\lnot z$ and $¬z ∧ r → ¬s$ derive $\lnot s$ [with [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) and Modus ponens].

With $\lnot s$ and $s ∨ ¬w$ derive $¬w$ [with [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism)].